# How to change port on built ASP .NET API

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to make a simple REST API with ASP .NET and when i run the API on my computer the port is whatever i specify. However when it is published and run on my server it is always port 5000. Better yet, the swagger UI doesn't show either. I can provide additional information if you need it! Thanks!

Hardware: RPI 3B+
OS: Raspbian (latest)

**LaunchSettings.json:**

```
{
  "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
        "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:3061",
        "sslPort": 44303
      }
    },
    "profiles": {
      "SS_API": {
        "commandName": "Project",
        "dotnetRunMessages": true,
        "launchBrowser": true,
        "launchUrl": "swagger",
        "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7009;http://localhost:5009;https://0.0.0.0:5001",
        "environmentVariables": {
          "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
        }
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you tell us more about the server environment? Operating system, web server stack (IIS, etc)?

Comment: Raspbian, RPI 3B+, i'm not sure about the web server stack. How do i check?

Answer (score 0):

Check launchSettings.json.
Maybe your application is using different launch profile when it starts up on this environment. If you are using IIS - also check web.config file

Comment: Hey! thanks for the response! I dont see a web.config file, where is that? Also i'm sorry for being such a novice but i'm not really sure how to check the launch profile. I left my launchSettings.json in my post. Could you possibly tell me?

Comment: web.config ussually is in the root of the ASP.NET Core project. If it is not there, then, probaly, you are not using IIS.
About launchSettings.json - it is in the Properties folder in the root of ASP.NET Core project.

Comment: I guess I'm not using IIS then! My launchSettings.json is in the properties folder.